# performing search over list created by directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am very new to AngularJs, Somehow I am now able to create a directive which can be used for binding data from controller to html.Now I want to create a functionality like a search over the list which is shown on AngularJs.
This list contains different objects.
I have created the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YogCFtd7NwA4urhao464?p=preview) here

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="movieDesc">
    <diuv>
      <input type="text" placeholder="search"/>
      <input type="button" value="Search" />
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="m in movies" movies="m" save="saveData(movie)"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Controller**

```
   angular.module('app', []);

    angular.module('app').controller('movieDesc', function($scope) {

      $scope.movies = [{
        name: 'abc',
        desc: 'this is desc text for the movie',
        pic: 'http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/134/abstract-geometric-background-triangle-and-square-black_134053397.jpg'
      }, {
        name: 'def',
        desc: 'this is desc text for the movie def',
        pic: 'http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/201/abstract-modern-banner-background-of-geometric-shapes-abstract-geometric-form_201768245.jpg'
      }, {
        name: 'ghi',
        desc: 'this is desc text for the movie ghi',
        pic: 'http://www.cianellistudios.com/images/abstract-art/abstract-art-infinite-150.jpg'
      }]

      $scope.saveData = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }

    });
```

**My Directive**

```
angular.module('app').directive('movies', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: "movieCard.html",
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
      movies: '=',
      save: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       console.log("link function called");
      element.addClass('moviesBox');
      var clickedFn = function() {
        alert("clicked");
      };
      console.log("console", element[0].querySelector('.btnSelect'));
      var $this = element[0].querySelector('.btnSelect');
      $($this).click(function() {
        alert(scope.movies.desc)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

**movieCard.html**

```
<div>
  <div>
    <b>Name:</b> {{movies.name}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>Description:</b> {{movies.desc}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <img ng-src="{{movies.pic}}" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="movies.someText">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="btnSelect" type="button" value="Desc" ng-click="clickedFn()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="btnSelect" type="button" value="Save Data" ng-click="save({movie: movies})">
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a search button in HTML, so on that I want to perform that search option, where I can type and get that list only which I search

Comment: Use `ng-click` and `ng-class` instead of writing own code in directive

Comment: If my post was usefull, please mark it as answer

Comment: let me once achieve the functionality, I will definately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this with 2 options.
1. Use smth like this.

```
<input type="button" value="Search" data-ng-click=filter(key) data-ng-model="key" />

$scope.filter = function(key){
$scope.filteredMovies = $scope.movies.filter(function filterByName(movie){
   return movie.name.indexOf(key) !==-1;
 });
};
```

When you click, this code will filter you list and only filtered itmes will be presente on filteredMovies .

2. Same behavior you can achive using angular filter from there: 
   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

> Usage
>   In HTML Template Binding
>   {{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}
>   In JavaScript
>   $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)

```
angular.module('app').filter('superFilter', function(){ 
return function(list, key){ 
if (!key) { 
return list; 

} 
return list.filter(function filterByName(movie) { 
return movie.name.indexOf(key) !== -1; 
}); 
} 

});
```

But be care with filter :)

Comment: are you sure we do not have to change anything in directives, as simply typing in textbox and clicking button doesnt work for me

Comment: If you use first approach you should remember, that your filtered data now stored in other variable - filteredMovies and you need to bind it to your view

Comment: data-ng-model="key"  
This means that key will be that you type in this input :)

Comment: ok, getting your point, but how come search box gets binds automatically, this is what I am failing to understand. I have updated my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YogCFtd7NwA4urhao464?p=preview)

Comment: There are no magic here. When you click on search button, filteredMovies function will be executed. Because we used ng-model, we have created variable that stores search input text. So our function will filter your list, and then, angular will start digest. When digest will see, that your list was changed from last digest, it will re render your list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114348/discussion-between-abhishek-asthana-and-vitalii).